# This error occurred while trying to install nextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, installation, error-handling, next.js

This type of error occurs when I am trying to install next.js in the command line. How can I fix this issue?

This is the error log:

```
PS C:\Users\N\OneDrive\Dokumente\Coding\React\#2> npx create-next-app nextjs-blog --use-npm --example "https://github.com/vercel/next-learn-starter/tree/master/learn-starter"
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'C:\Users\N'
TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at errorMessage (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-message.js:38:39)
    at errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:201:13)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js:78:20
    at cb (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:225:22)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js:263:24
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:81:7
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:80:13
    at f (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at afterExtras (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\config\core.js:171:20)
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97
  var doExit = npm.config.loaded ? npm.config.get('_exit') : true
                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'loaded' of undefined
    at exit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:97:27)
    at process.errorHandler (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:216:3)
    at process.emit (events.js:210:5)
    at process._fatalException (internal/process/execution.js:150:25)
Install for [ 'create-next-app@latest' ] failed with code 7
```

Comment: Could you paste the error msg as text to your answer instead of a screenshot?

Comment: Do you perhaps have a space in your username?